# How to know the number of bytes based upon length in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm getting around 2500-4500 characters when i use listagg function. I already know that listagg function is limited up to 4000 bytes. But i'm curious to know about how many characters it takes to equals 4000 bytes or at least how the oracle calculates bytes based upon characters. Can anyone please help me with this.

The datatype used for the field is Varchar2(255 bytes)

From that field i'm concatenating the string and getting around 2500-4500 characters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the [NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams127.htm#REFRN10124). So whatever is your character set, that much space will be occupied by your character. For example in US7ASCII 1 CHAR = 1 BYTE whereas in  UTF8 1 CHAR = 1 to many BYTES.

Comment: I'm using Byte format. Can you please tell me about that?

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

It will probably be [AL32UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which is a variable width multi-byte character set. Standard ASCII characters will take a single byte, while accented or non-English characters often take three or four.